# Text variables in MS Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

If I have some kind of template like

```
Dear [Customer name].

You have an appointment with [Doctor's Name] on [Date].

Kind regards, 


[Secretary's name].
```

Now I want to be able to easily and conveniently fill out these variables, and have them inserted throughout the document where referenced. How would I do this?

NB. The problem I'm having with asking this question, is what terms to use. As a computer programmer, I would call these *variables*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sending out something like a letter or labels with this information as above you would use mail merge.  You would have the main file with the constant information and another file like an excel file with the information to go into these variables.  There is plenty of information on 'Mail Merge Word 2010' online.

If you are using the file like a form for someone to fill in these areas you would use fields.  Again plenty of information online such as: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-steps-to-creating-a-word-input-form.

Comment: For the record, it's not for a letter, but a technical document where various variables change. Thanks for the pointer, I'll check that out.